# Find most frequent number

Tags: java

I am new in Java. this is my homework, but I cannot fix it. Anyone want to help me? Thanks.
This program will take a list of single digits, entered at the command line when running the program, and find the digit entered most frequently.

This is my code.

```
public class MostFrequent{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int num = 0;
        int []freq= new int[10];//0-9
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            try{
                num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                freq[num]++;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            }
        }
        int max= 0, j;
        for (j=1; j<args.length; j++){
            while(freq[j]>freq[max]){
                max=j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + max);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: As a side note: You probably shouldn't be swallowing exceptions like that.

Comment: that `while` should be an `if`, even though in this case it does the same thing ;-)

Comment: when I run it, it shows 0. and I cannot put number in the code. I need entered number at the command line when running the program, and find the digit entered most frequently. I really don't know how to do it. I tried lots of times.

Comment: @Jasonzsjy, you really should add that comment to the question.

Comment: Look at Scanner class.

Comment: Well - we are not solving homeworks here. But a little hint: You are trying to find the most frequent digit in your second for-loop - why are you checking for args.length then? The only possible digits (and therefor the only available indices in your freq-Array are 0-9.

Comment: My English is not good so I don't know what should I do, here is the requirement of my homework.you must loop through the elements of args, turn each element in it into an integer using Integer.parseInt(),

Comment: and then increment the element in freq for this digit. 

Integer.parseInt() takes a string and converts it into an integer. 

Now you need to loop through freq and the maximum number of times a digit appeared on the command line. 

Notice that there could be more than one digit that appeared this maximum number of times. 

Once you have this maximum, loop through freq and print the digits that appeared this number of times.

Comment: Notice that there could be more than one digit that appeared this maximum number of times. 

So you will need three for loops
Loop through the args array to load freq with a count for each digit
Loop through the freq array to find the largest count for any digit
Loop through the freq array and when the count for a digit matches the maximum count.

Comment: The reason for showing 0 might be sign of not-passing the arguments. Your code worked well when I compiled it. If you are compiling your code via Eclipse, you can add arguments by right-clicking your MostFrequent.java from Project Explorer, click Properties, select MostFrequent class and click Edit. From new window, click on Arguments tab and type your arguments to "Program arguments" field. That should work. Also, as Edgar mentioned, you should use if condition instead of while in your second for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles and runs fine. I, like the commenters, am pretty sure that your problem lies in that you are not passing any arguments.

Assuming you are working on the command line:

**String[] args** is a list of arguments that you pass in at run time, like the following

**java MostFrequent 4 6 3 6 7 5 3 2 4 6 8 4 3 5 6**

I would like to know, what array of numbers did you think that you were scanning over?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you can make the freq counting a little simpler like this:

```
public class MostFrequent{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] freq= new int[10];//0-9
        for (String arg : args) {
            try {
                freq[Integer.parseInt(arg)]++;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }
        }
        int max= 0, j;
        for (j=1; j<args.length; j++) {
            while(freq[j]>freq[max]) {
                max=j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The digit that appears most frequently is " + max);
    }
}
```

Some do not like exception based preogramming but for checking user input in cases like this the simplicity and readability far outweigh performance concerns.